# How to commit a file conversion?

Tags: version-control

Say you've committed a file of type *foo* in your favorite `vcs`:

```
$ vcs add data.foo
$ vcs commit -m "My data"
```

After publishing you realize there's a better data format *bar*. To convert you can use one of these solutions:

```
$ vcs mv data.foo data.bar
$ vcs commit -m "Preparing to use format bar"
$ foo2bar --output data.bar data.bar
$ vcs commit -m "Actual foo to bar conversion"
```

or

```
$ foo2bar --output data.foo data.foo
$ vcs commit -m "Converted data to format bar"
$ vcs mv data.foo data.bar
$ vcs commit -m "Renamed to fit data type"
```

or

```
$ foo2bar --output data.bar data.foo
$ vcs rm data.foo
$ vcs add data.bar
$ vcs commit -m "Converted data to format bar"
```

In the first two cases the conversion is not an atomic operation and *the file extension is "lying"* in the first commit. In the last case the conversion will not be detected as a move operation, so as far as I can tell it'll be *difficult to trace the file history* across the commit. Although I'd instinctively prefer the last solution, I can't help thinking that tracing history should be given very high priority in version control. What is the best thing to do here?

Comment: Your question seems specific to Git, because the commands match and you say "the conversion will not be detected". Some other source control systems specifically track renames so this wouldn't be an issue at all. You might get better answers if you specifically refer to Git in your question.

Comment: Either that or he's specifically asking about Subversion which does different things if you `mv` versus `rm/add`.

Comment: Looks like Subversion tracks moves [explicitly](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/32402-Does-Subversion-keeps-file-history-after-move-or-rename), and Git [implicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history).

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer the last solution.

However, regardless of what solution you choose, you should make sure that you record the exact version and arguments of the converter tool in the commit message. The reason for this is that in all three solutions the diff(s) simply won't make sense. You simply cannot sensibly review the commits.

But what you *can* do, is checkout the *old* commit, run the tool *yourself* and verify that its output matches the *new* commit. That way, you don't have to trust the huge unreadable diff, you only have to trust the tool.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in git (and others like it as well), it doesn't matter whether you specifically move the file or not. The information about the move operation isn't stored in the repository. Git calculates it based on file similarity when you're working with the history. If the converted file is very different from the original (which I'd guess is likely), it won't know the two files are related, regardless of what order you commit things. If the converted file is similar, it will know the two files are related, regardless of whether you use `git mv` or `git add` on one file and `git rm` on the other. (`git mv` is simply shorthand for those two commands).

But you're talking about subversion specifically, where the `svn mv` command is recorded in the repository, and I can't answer what the best practice should be, because I dont use subversion anymore, though I'll say that your line of reasoning definitely makes sense.

Comment: It looks like [Git can follow the history across renames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2314757/96588) if the content doesn't change "too much" in the same commit, and this is precisely the issue: Even a binary conversion should be a single commit, but should be easily traversed in the log.

Comment: @l0b0: I see now... your two-commit solutions are intended to change the content of the file in one commit, and then change the name in another commit. I guess those work, but I remember reading that Linus just objects to the whole idea of tracking the history of individual files. Following his line of reasoning, you'd use a single-commit solution, and generally restrict yourself to looking at repository history as a whole, or the history of subtrees that don't move around. You don't have to subscribe to his line of thinking, but if you don't, individual file history is a little hacky.